# add autoplay to youtube iframe on button click jquery not working

Tags: jquery

I am using custom buttons to keep my design consistent. I have added a button which is layered on top of the `iframe` using the `z-index` property in CSS. Onclick the `iframe` reacts but does not begin to play. I have used this code on other websites and it worked fine.

This code works in Safari but not in Chrome. I am not sure if maybe I should try re-installing Chrome.

I have also added 1 other lines which I have tried (commented out). Can anyone suggest why this is not working on chrome?

```
$('#playLucid').click(function() {
  $('#playLucid').css('display', 'none');
  //$("#expose").attr('src','https://www.youtube.com/embed/7bU-x8pJbig?autoplay=1');
  $("#expose")[0].src += "?autoplay=1";
});
```

Comment: What type of element is `#expose`? Also note that Chrome has strict rules on when it will/will not allow a video to be auto played. I'd suggest you read [this guide](https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2017/09/autoplay-policy-changes) to ensure you're following them fully.

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan              <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-12 attitude">
                <iframe class="expose" id="expose" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/7bU-x8pJbig" frameborder="0"></iframe>
            </div>

Comment: here is the HTML

Answer (score 5):

This May Work:

```
<iframe type="text/html" 
    src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/..?autoplay=1" frameborder="0" 
    allow="autoplay">
</iframe>
```

If it doesn't work, try adding `mute=1` or `muted=1`:

```
src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/..?autoplay=1&mute=1
```

Comment: I needed to add "allow="autoplay". This helped me find the solution. So thank you.

Comment: @Alex, your fix worked for me, after allowing autoplay it worked for me, so thank you.

Answer (score 2):

The Solution is to add autoplay after clicking your button, this is an example:

```
$('#button-open-video').click(function(event) {
    var video = $('#youtube').attr('src');
    $('#youtube').attr('src', `${video}&autoplay=1`)  // adding autoplay to the URL
    $('#video').css('display','block');
});
```

For More Details see this example: [Click Here](https://codepen.io/mohamedmazraoui/pen/poRzWrX)

Good luck